# Calculate total by summing max numbers

Tags: reporting-services

I have a Matrix report that has two row groups and two column groups. There is column which has the calculation Max(Fields!AdjustedManning.Value) on the Row Group level as a subtotal. I want to add a total at the bottom which is outside of the row group to sum the subtotal numbers up. What expression can I use to do this? Effectively I'm looking to sum the max numbers

In the image the yellow box for design is where I need to put the expression and a preview of what I would expect it to calculate.

[Design and Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tGga.png)

Comment: what happens if you sum the report item? Say the text box name for the cell max(adjusted..) is called max_adjusted_text.. simply use the expression =Sum(Reportitems!max_adjusted_text.value) in the yellow total cell. does it give you the desired result?

Comment: I get the following error The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox174.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' uses an aggregate function on a report item.  Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the rowgroup names so I'm guessing you have a rowgroup grouped by `[WoLine]` called `Woline`. Assuming this is correct then you should be able to use something like...

```
=SUM(MAX(Fields!AdjustedManning.Value, "WoLine"))
```

`"WoLine"` is the name of the rowgroup, you must include the quotes and it is case sensitive so adjust to suit your actual report.

What this does is get the MAX value within the "WoLine" rowgroup scope and then sum the results.

Comment: Yes sorry, that is the rowgroup. In the end I went about solving it a different way by pre-calculating the numbers I needed in SQL and using a Lookup function to get them. I just tried your way and it gave me an error of [rsNestedAggregateScopesFromDifferentAxes] The Value expression for the text box 'Textbox85' uses both row and column scopes or scopes from two different data axes in the same aggregate expression

Comment: without seeing the row and column groups in your design it was difficult to give a full answer, the column scope would be implicit as the cell falls within a column group

Comment: Apologies, I'll make sure to include them in my next question if I have one. Thanks for your input.